# Live Search Using Laravel

Tags: laravel, search

I can't find any good plugins for a live search using Laravel, does one exist? I've found a few jQuery autocomplete plugins but I'm looking for something like this: https://github.com/iranianpep/ajax-live-search

I tried implementing the above yesterday (for about 10 hours) and couldn't get it to work due to the MySQL queries they use vs Laravel's implementation

**any** thoughts or information is appreciated

I also tried using a large Laravel query to receive data (I want to search more than one column) but using the

```
User::where('name', 'like', $query)->orWhere('username', 'like', $query)->etc.
```

format didn't even match the name for me. Is there such a thing as a more advanced algorithm to search?

Thanks

- Zach

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Scout is your answer.

> Laravel Scout provides a simple, driver based solution for adding full-text search to your Eloquent models. Using model observers, Scout will automatically keep your search indexes in sync with your Eloquent records.
>
> Currently, Scout ships with an Algolia driver; however, writing custom drivers is simple and you are free to extend Scout with your own search implementations.

I would personally recommend Algolia as well, as it is very sophisticated, has a free entry level, and is better than any search you could come up with by yourself.

You can set the ranking yourself in their backend, it will regard typos made in your search, and so much more. Plus it is cloud powered!

With Laravel Scout any searching is made a breeze just like:

```
$users = App\User::search('Chris')->get();
```

What's really cool:

```
$users = App\User::search('Chrs')->get();
```

Both `$users` return the same results. Even with a typo.

For more information you can read up in the official [Laravel Scout documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scout).

If you are a member of Laracasts, check out [these screencasts](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/94). And even if you are not, it's really cheap and you will learn a lot on Laravel Scout and live search!

Comment: I'll check it out thank you! Been pounding my head into the sand to try to get a simple search working

Comment: I am working on search myself right now, and Scout and Algolia make it unbelievably easy.